# Django: allow language prefix and root url

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have a Django application with multiple languaje, in this moment I have the language prefix activated in this way:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    ...,
    prefix_default_language=True,
    )
```

And when I load the website in the home url: mysite.com/ it redirects to mysite.com/en/ (the default language)

but I need to load mysite.com/ as home without the redirection and mysite.com/en/ also as home (just when the user load that exact url)

Comment: Why are you passing `prefix_default_language=True` if you don't want it to prefix default language?

Comment: I want both, I need that the same page load with and without the language prefix

Answer (score 1):

If you visit `mysite.com`, Django automatically adds the default language code to the URL, `mysite.com/en/`. So that users will get the same page when they visit `mysite.com` and `mysite.com/en`

If you don't want the language code for your default language, you can turn it off:

```
prefix_default_language=False,
```

Unfortunately, if you turn off prefix_default_language, then `mysite.com/en` will no longer work. If you really want that to work too, you could write a url rule `/en` to point to your homepage as well.

Comment: I want both, I need that the users access home from mysite.com/ but also from mysite.com/en/

Comment: @Nazkter You could write a url rule to point /en to your homepage. This will only work for your homepage and not for sub folders such as mysite.com/en/something-else

Comment: Then just add an url pattern with a redirect from mysite.com/en to mysite.com. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: @Nazkter Currently there doesn't seem to be a way around this. I prefer to keep the prefix for default language as well for consistency